# iOS not respecting URL parameters in SMS messages

Tags: ios, twilio

My app sends unique URLs to users, there's a URL parameter that unique identifies that particular user.

For example:

```
Hi. Here's your password reset token:

https://myapp.com/password/reset/1111-2222-3333-4444
```

In iOS, when opening the link in the SMS message the browser opens up `https://myapp.com/` *without* the rest of the URL.

Is there some special encoding iOS requires for URLs in SMS messages to open properly?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a domain redirecting issue where a `#` was inserted in the URL and client's couldn't follow it properly.